# setState not working

Tags: reactjs

```
class Assets extends React.Component{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
          assets: [],
          secondsElapsed: 0
        };
    }

tick() {
    if(start === true){

      fetch('/api/user/all/?name='+name, {credentials: 'include', method: 'get'}).then(function(data){
        return data.json();
      }).then( json => {
        this.setState({
            assets: json
          });
      });
      }
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<Assets />, document.getElementById('alerts'));
```

This code is throwing this error when run:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundleAlerts.js:3430), <anonymous>:265:15)
    at <anonymous>
```

The code is been complied by webpack if that makes a difference. I was using the ReactCreate class before and it worked fine then but I changed it in an attempt to fix another error.

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: i think binding issue, use this: `then((data) => {....`

Comment: You're right. The `then..` portion was hiding. I had to scroll the code window to see.

Comment: I'm been really dumb her but what part am I replacing with `then((data) => {....`

Comment: Proper formatting makes these errors much easier to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your `tick` function to your component. :) It was currently binded to the function and not to the class component therefore it could not access ‘this’, which means it won’t be able to access your props or state. You can either use the example below, autobind decorator (ES7) or transform class properties ‘tick = () => { ... }’.

```js
class Assets extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      assets: [],
      secondsElapsed: 0
    };
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }
  tick() {
    if (start === true) {
      fetch("/api/user/all/?name=" + name, {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "get"
      })
        .then(data => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({
            assets: json
          });
        });
    }
  }
  // ...rest of component
}

ReactDOM.render(<Assets />, document.getElementById("alerts"));
```

Comment: Did you forget anything? :) What will this component show?

Comment: You might want to explain why this is necessary.